# Reacting to media query in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, media-queries

I am trying to listen to resize events with browser and upon crossing a threshold of < 48 rem, send a "xs" => exta small request header to server. On the contrary, for > 48 rem, will send "sm" => small

so far, came up with this -

```
if (matchMedia) {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 48rem)");
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is less than 48rem
    (function(send) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
            // in this case I'm injecting an access token (eg. accessToken) in the request headers before it gets sent
            this.setRequestHeader('x-size-token', ' ');
            this.setRequestHeader('x-size-token', "xs");
            send.call(this, data);
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);  
  } else {
    // window width is at least 48rem
     (function(send) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
            // in this case I'm injecting an access token (eg. accessToken) in the request headers before it gets sent
            this.setRequestHeader('x-size-token', ' ');
            this.setRequestHeader('x-size-token', "sm");
            send.call(this, data);
        };
     })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
  }

}
```

this is appending to request header in this way :

```
sm
xs,sm
sm,xs,sm
```

So basically, is not oeverwriting old one and instead it seems is appending to it.

Is their way that only one thing goes to requestHeader  , either xs/ sm ?

**EDIT:**

As per some suggestions to reload on each resize event , it surely works but I won't be able to reload on each resize event as there is lot of state that can be lost :

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){location.reload();});
```

Comment: on resize reload the page will help you.

Comment: currently website reloads forcibly only when orientation changes in mobiles. Any other way ?

Comment: reload the page on resize google will help you.

Comment: That should work but there is lot of state without URL for each state in web and refresh is going to loose that. Is there no way to clear request header for a key ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear HTTP headers for AJAX GET calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602065/how-can-i-clear-http-headers-for-ajax-get-calls)

Comment: We can't replace request header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems to be working for me is below :

```
function WidthChange(mq) {
      if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is less than 48rem
        $.ajaxSetup({
             headers : {
                 "x-size-token" : "xs"
             }
         }); 
      } else {
        // window width is at least 48rem
        $.ajaxSetup({
             headers : {
                 "x-size-token" : "sm"
             }
        });
      }
    }
```

So instead of intercepting ajax call and setting request headers in vanilla JS, I am using jquery ajaxSetup to set headers for me and now I find even without reload while resizing, the next ajax request takes correct value without appending to old one as :

```
xs
sm
xs
```